# php mail multiple recepients

Tags: php, email

I am able to send email to one email id by defining the id in the mailer, but i am not able to understand how to send to multiple recepients when an  user types "mssage and email id's" in a form. Ex - I am showing a form with two text areas - one for email id's and one for custom message. So when they click send, i want to take the email id's from that text area and send that message to those ids. I am yet to figure out how to comma/space seperate the emailds but will try it in google search.

thanks

Comment: I've added a link to a tutorial you may find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing some search, I came with this answer to send multiple address seperated by semicolon(for some reason my try with comma in this code failed, but i am fine with semicolon).

If in case if anyone is looking for JS validation to check the id's entered

```
var emailRegex = /^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$/;
```

As i collected the email id's separated by semicolon, i had to replace ; with ,

```
$emails_tosend = preg_replace('/;/', ',', $emailid);
```

$email id - collected from the form

so after doing the above replacement, i just use the normal "to" in the mailer to send to multiple recipients.

```
$to = "$emails_tosend";
mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

hope this helps and it's clear. I can explain if anyone needs more clarification. thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of the `to` parameter for the `mail()` function states:

```
Receiver, or receivers of the mail.

The formatting of this string must comply with » RFC 2822. Some examples are:

    * user@example.com
    * user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com
    * User <user@example.com>
    * User <user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Update:

I've come across this great tutorial on sending mail with PHP:
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/advanced-email-php

Comment: hi,

thanks, i managed to send multiple emails and i am planning to post the code sometime today once i clean it up little bit. now i am stuck with sending automated emails via cron. this is what i need - while the admin send emails, i store the message, emails, event date in the database. now i am trying to set  acron job to send emails to all these ids from the table with the message i have as a reminder. i am not familiar with cron job scripting, can anyone help in guiding me the right way to write scrip that i can place in cron tab.thanks

Comment: I agree with your point, as I mentioned in one other question, I definitely give credits once I am done with my work based on the answers and comments. May be there is a delay but I do it without fail. I will post my cron job question in a bit. thanks. I added that as a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368307/how-to-send-emails-via-cron-job-usng-php-mysql

Answer (score 3):

It's far easier to use something like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) (free, easy to install, easy to use) if you have to do anything even "moderately" complicated, like multiple recipients for an email. It'll hide all the ugly details for you behind a nice interface. Instead of worrying about header syntaxes and whatnot, you just do something like:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddAddress('address1@example.com');
$mail->AddAddress('address2@someotherplace.com');
etc...
```

Comment: +1 a good idea, though I think it's essential to know what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Separate their addresses with commas.