# PHP automatic mail sending

Tags: php, mysql, email, mail-server

How can I generate automatic mail sending logic using PHP at the end of the month in an application?

Comment: Hi Virat. Unfortunately there isn't nearly enough information there for people to usefully help you. Use cron (or Windows Scheduler) plus a PHP script, your MySQL database and an email library, such as SwiftMailer. Let this question close, give it a try, and come back with a specific question if you get stuck. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should use cron job here.

Develop a script to send email at the end of the month and run it through cron job.

Please also visit link for [How to send emails via cron job using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368307/how-to-send-emails-via-cron-job-usng-php-mysql). and [how to set up cron job.](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)