# How to send email to huge numbers of registered email by using background-process php script?

Tags: php, email, background-process

I have a `users` table in my database. There have 50,000 above email addresses. I want to send email to all at a time. I am using `while` loop. But my browser hang during send mail. How to send email to all users?

Code:

```
$qryUserEmail = mysql_query("SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE is_active=1");
if(mysql_num_rows($qryUserEmail)){ //I got 50624 email addresses.
  while($getUserEmail = mysql_fetch_array($qryUserEmail)){
      //Sending Email code Here...
  }
}
```

I don't know about `background-process` code. If anybody know please post your answer here. How to send email without taking any time for my related code?

Comment: Send from command line using cron.

Comment: @ShellFish can you post your answer about command line cron.

Answer (score 1):

Php should be able to start background processes, but I don't know much about that.

I would suggest that you introduce some kind of a queue and  background worker that can send the email without direct interaction from the user.

So when the user clicks 'send', a job is added to the queue, and once in a while, queued jobs are handled (like cron job or similar)

Another alternative is to pay for a service like send grid or mailchimp.

Comment: How to set mail in queue?

Comment: @chatfun have a new table, the queue, where you add a record about the news you wanna send. The key the background worker read that table and do the actual sending, just like you do now.

Comment: I don't want to use any third party api.

Comment: Vegar I have updated my code. Please check. I don't need any 3rd party. I want to write code in my own script.

Comment: Using 3rd party code is one of the best way of coding. Not copy-paste but using libraries maintained and tested by many others.

Comment: https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Cron-Job-Tutorial-Automate-the-Email-Sending-for-Newsletter  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368307/how-to-send-emails-via-cron-job-usng-php-mysql  https://florian.ec/articles/running-background-processes-in-php/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78745/discussion-between-chatfun-and-vegar).

Answer (score 0):

1. use `set_time_limit()` and `ini_set('max_execution_time')` to increase the time of execution.
2. You can execute .PHP file from shell script (or something like crontab) or browser.

   It's not necessary to use callback function or something else.
   Post your email send in your while or use CC and BCC.